# Hyperjaxb 3 imported XSD and persistence.xml

Tags: java, xml, hyperjaxb

This is my first attempt of using Hyperjaxb3. I have a snippet of my 2 XSD as shown below

**ContractFullInfo.xsd**

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://homecredit.net/homerselect/common/v1" schemaLocation="Common.xsd"/>

<xsd:element name = "ContractFullInfoRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="systemEvent" type="common:ContractSystemEventType"/>
            <xsd:element name="data" type="ContractFullInfo"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="ContractPerson">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="cuid" type="xsd:long"/>
        <xsd:element name="personRole" type="PersonRoleType"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

**Common.xsd**

```
<xsd:complexType name="ContractPerson">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="cuid" type="xsd:long"/>
        <xsd:element name="personRole" type="PersonRoleType"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The problem with this it generates two ContractPerson classes as shown below:

```
        <class>net.homecredit.homerselect.common.v1.ContractPerson</class> <==
        <class>net.homecredit.homerselect.common.v1.MoneyDto</class>
        <class>net.homecredit.homerselect.contract.v3.BankAccount</class>
        <class>net.homecredit.homerselect.contract.v3.ClosedEndParameter</class>
        <class>net.homecredit.homerselect.contract.v3.ContractBase</class>
        <class>net.homecredit.homerselect.contract.v3.ContractCommodity</class>
        <class>net.homecredit.homerselect.contract.v3.ContractDocument</class>
        <class>net.homecredit.homerselect.contract.v3.ContractEvent</class>
        <class>net.homecredit.homerselect.contract.v3.ContractFullInfo</class>
        <class>net.homecredit.homerselect.contract.v3.ContractFullInfoRequest</class>
        <class>net.homecredit.homerselect.contract.v3.ContractParameter</class>
        <class>net.homecredit.homerselect.contract.v3.ContractPerson</class> <==
        <class>net.homecredit.homerselect.contract.v3.ContractService</class>
        <class>net.homecredit.homerselect.contract.v3.RefinancedContract</class>
        <class>net.homecredit.homerselect.contract.v3.RevolvingParameter</class>
```

and it gives me error during deployment as

```
 Entity name must be unique in a persistence unit. Entity name [ContractPerson] is used for the entity classes [net.homecredit.homerselect.common.v1.ContractPerson] and [net.homecredit.homerselect.contract.v3.ContractPerson].
```

A portion of my Java configuration (which I currently commented)

```
  @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
        return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.jndi-name"));
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws NamingException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"net.homecredit.homerselect.contract.v3"});
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("net.homecredit.homerselect.common.v1:net.homecredit.homerselect.contract.v3");
        em.setJtaDataSource(dataSource());

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        em.setJpaProperties(properties);

        return em;
    }
```

My questions:

1. Both classes are exactly the same. How can I pick one ?
2. I am using Spring Boot, is there a way to **override persistence.xml** using Spring Boot java configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes are not the same as you have two different complex types in your schema. They also probably reference different `PersonRoleType`s, but it's hard to say without seeing your complete schemas.

While it's not impossible to map these complex types onto the same Java class, I won't do it. These are distinct types in your schemas, you should keep them distinct in Java as well.

Since you get a problem with classes having the same local name, the easiest solution would be to rename one of them. Use a binding like:

```
<jaxb:bindings
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:hj="http://hyperjaxb3.jvnet.org/ejb/schemas/customizations"
    xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc hj orm">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="Common.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='ContractPerson']">
            <jaxb:class name="CommonContractPerson"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```